# Conditional Cfloop code to place AND at first loop

Tags: coldfusion

Using the following query, I am trying to do a simple case here when the first record it encounters it should basically add "`AND`" and for the remaining conditions, I want to add `OR`

Here is my try

```
<cfif isDefined('age') and len(trim(age)) and age neq '-1'>
   <cfset age = trim(htmlEditFormat(lcase(age)))>
   <cfloop list="#age#" index="k">
       or age between #ListFirst(k,'-')# and #ListLast(k,'-')#
   </cfloop>
</cfif>
```

trying to make it work like this

```
and (age between 18 and 20 
or age between 20 and 25 
or age between 25 and 30)
```

I am not getting where I should add a condition to add parenthesis and the `AND` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something as similar as adding a false statement and then looping through everything else as needed

```
<cfif isDefined('age') and len(trim(age)) and age neq '-1'>
  <cfset age = trim(htmlEditFormat(lcase(age)))>
  AND (1 = 2 --always returns false
  <cfloop list="#age#" index="k">
    OR age between #ListFirst(k,'-')# and #ListLast(k,'-')#
  </cfloop>
  )
</cfif>
```

This is what you were trying to do

```
<cfif isDefined('age') and len(trim(age)) and age neq '-1'>
  <cfset age = trim(htmlEditFormat(lcase(age)))>
  AND (
  <cfloop list="#age#" index="k">
    <cfif listFirst(age) NEQ k> OR </cfif> --if it's not the first iteration, add the OR
    age between #ListFirst(k,'-')# and #ListLast(k,'-')#
  </cfloop>
  )
</cfif>
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, thi is all what i was trying to do

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that doesn't require an `if` block and would work for any type of loop:

```
<cfif isDefined('age') and len(trim(age)) and age neq '-1'>
   <cfset age = trim(htmlEditFormat(lcase(age)))>
   <cfset expressionSeparator = "">
   AND (
   <cfloop list="#age#" index="k">
       #expressionSeparator#
       age between #ListFirst(k,'-')# and #ListLast(k,'-')#
       <cfset expressionSeparator = " or ">
   </cfloop>
   )
</cfif>
```